# Dynamically alter traceback/stack frame function name

Tags: python, traceback

From time to time, I write a generic function in Python that gets called multiple times with different arguments. Usually, this is driven by a definition somewhere else.

For example:

```
def issue_sql_query(name, select_stmt):
    ...

QUERIES = [
    "get_user_rows", "SELECT name, rowid FROM table WHERE type == 'USER';"
    ...
]

results = []
for name, select_stmt in QUERIES:
    results.append((name, issue_sql_query(name, select_stmt)))
```

If there's an exception in the generic function (i.e., issue_sql_query or somewhere deeper), I have relatively little info in the traceback to identify which definition caused the error.

What I'd like to do is dynamically rename or augment the function name/stack frame so that tracebacks would include some identifying info.

What would be nice is something like this:

```
File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    results.append((name, issue_sql_query(select_stmt)))
File "test.py", line 11, in issue_sql_query(name="get_user_rows")
    raise RuntimeError("Some error")
RuntimeError: Some error
```

I could, of course, stick exception handling at the generic points and rebuild the exception using traceback to have more context, which is pretty straightforward and likely the right choice. It gets a little tricky when you have multiple levels of generic functions, but that's certainly possible to handle.

Any other ideas on how to accomplish this? Did I miss some easy way to change the stack frame name?

Edit:
Adding an example traceback showing a relatively not useful traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\tmp\report.py", line 767, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\tmp\report.py", line 750, in main
    charts.append(report.get_chart(title, definition))
  File "c:\tmp\report.py", line 614, in get_chart
    return self.get_bar_chart(title, definition)
  File "c:\tmp\report.py", line 689, in get_bar_chart
    definition, cursor, **kwargs))
  File "c:\tmp\report.py", line 627, in create_key_table
    for row in cursor.execute(full_select_stmt):
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "==": syntax error
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is going wrong, or the sub-optimal traceback?

Comment: Why aren't you passing `name` as an argument to `issue_sql_query()`?

Comment: Matt, I added an example of one I got from my real code.

Comment: What about using try-except-blocks which capture any external functions and its errors and raise your own exception? For a first overview you might have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

You could create wrapper functions for each named query so that you can control the exception thrown:

```
>>> fns = {}
>>> def issue_sql_query(name, stmt):
...   if name not in fns:
...     def f(name, stmt):
...       # run query here
...       raise Exception(name)
...
...     fns[name] = f
...   return fns[name](name, stmt)
...
>>>
>>> issue_sql_query('b', 'SQL')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in issue_sql_query
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f
Exception: b
>>> issue_sql_query('a', 'SQL')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in issue_sql_query
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f
Exception: a
>>>
```